# Angular 9 front/corsheaders django 3 back - appending the CORS headers to the request

Tags: django, angular

having the problem to find a way how to configure properly front end app in Angular 9 consuming back REST webservice. On the remote server with the static IP i run my angular dev server with (i know it is only for dev purposes but i want to get rid of this error first)

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`

so i can access it from the outside. then i have my django app also with the dev server at

`127.0.0.1:8000`

In the angular service.ts file i am trying to inject the header

```
export class FlightService {

  httpOptions = { 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Request-Method':'GET',
      'Access-Control-Request-Headers':'origin, x-requested-with, accept'
    })
  };

  private endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/services';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  //GET All Services
  getAllServices(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.endpoint, this.httpOptions)
  }
}
```

In the settings.py of my django backend i have put at the top the corsheaders module:

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
```

and allowed all the host (after trying many things with whitelist which none of worked:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False 

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
 #   'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS'
    #'PATCH',
    #'POST',
    #'PUT',
]


CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
    'x-forwarded-for'
]
```

But I fail all the time. After i added the httpOptions i get the error in the browser:

**http.js:2403 Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"**

and as well:

**Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers"**

So at least i know the Angular is trying to append it.

Please help, how to approach it? I guess the problem is on the client side. I also tried to set up Nginx with a proxy to Angular dev, but also fail to append the headers on the Nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

These CORS headers are  not for you to set, the browser will do it automatically if it detects that you are trying to access cross domain resources.

Comment: How then i am able to get it working? If i do not set it, it also doesn’t work.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url].

Comment: I see also in the Firefox network tab that first attempt is sent as OPTIONS by xhr (initiator) and returned error is CORS failed. In the header of the request there is something like **Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin**. Do you know how to influence that OPTIONS preflight message?